# Time it takes a coin to fall in a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, torque, maxwell-equations

This was a homework problem of mine was:

"A coin is placed on its edge in a vertical magnetic field of $B=20$ T. The initial angle between the coin and vertical is $\theta_0=0.1$ rad. Estimate how long it takes the penny to fall. Take the conductivity of the coin to be $\sigma = 6\times10^5 (\Omega\cdot$cm$)^{-1}$, the mass density, $\rho = 9$ g/cm$^3$, the radius, $R=1$ cm, and the width, $\Delta=0.15$ cm. Assume that in the process of falling the gravitational torque always balances the magnetic torque, i.e. one can ignore the acceleration of the penny."

I got an answer of $19$ hours which seems unreasonable. I'd appreciate if someone could let me know if my reasoning is off anywhere?

Integrating Faraday's Law, $$\nabla\times\mathbf{E} = - \partial\mathbf{B}/\partial t$$ over the area of the coin, the change in flux through the coin is $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (B_0\pi R^2 \cos\theta) = B_0\omega \pi R^2 \sin\theta$$ and ignoring the minus sign since we're only interested in magnitudes, this is equal to $$\int \mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{l} = 2\pi R j/\sigma$$ using Ohm's Law, $\mathbf{j}=\sigma\mathbf{E}$. Then the current density $j=\sigma\omega B_0 R \sin\theta /2$.
Since $\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{I}\times\mathbf{B}$, I multiply the current density by an area $R\Delta$ and multiply by another $B_0$. Then $$F=\frac{1}{2}\sigma\omega B_0^2 R \sin\theta \cdot R\Delta.$$ Then torque $$\tau = FR = mgR\sin\theta = \frac{1}{2}\sigma\omega B_0^2 R \sin\theta R\Delta \cdot R.$$ This gets us the angular velocity $$\omega=2mg/\sigma R^2 B_0^2 \Delta$$ which we assume is constant. Finally, the coin falls when $\theta$ reaches $\pi/2$, which implies that the time it takes is $t=(\pi/2-\theta_0)/\omega$. Plugging in the values above gets me about $19$ hours.

Comment: I haven't had time to check this properly, but two points occur to me... (a) I get the dimensions of the right hand side of your final equation as L T^-1, not T^-1 as they should be. (b) I'm worried about how you're treating the currents. Surely their will be currents in the successive rings of increasing radii, from which the coin can be constructed.